# Exception in thread "broadcast-exchange-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Not enough memory to build and broadcast the table to all worker nodes

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am running a spark application on below configuration :

**1 Master , 2 Worker nodes.**

- Each worker has 88 Cores , hence total no. of cores 176
- Each worker has 502 GB memory , so total memory available is 1004 GB

I am getting below exception while running the application  :

```
Exception in thread "broadcast-exchange-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Not enough memory to build and broadcast the table to all worker nodes. As a workaround, you can either disable broadcast by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1 or increase the spark driver memory by setting spark.driver.memory to a higher value
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There are **two** solutions mentioned in this error itself :

1. *As a workaround, you can either disable broadcast by setting
   spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1.*

   **OR**
2. *Increase the spark driver memory by setting spark.driver.memory to a
   higher value.*

I am trying to run with setting more driver memory, however i want to understand the root cause of this issue. Can anyone please explain.

I have used **Java** in my code.

**EDIT 1**

I am using **broadcast variables** in my code.

**EDIT 2**

Adding code that contains broadcast variables.

```
//1.
        Dataset<Row> currencySet1 = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", CI_CURRENCY_CD).load();
        currencySetCache = currencySet1.select(CURRENCY_CD, DECIMAL_POSITIONS).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        Dataset<Row> currencyCodes = currencySetCache.select(CURRENCY_CD);
        currencySet = currencyCodes.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();

        //2.
        Dataset<Row>  divisionSet = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", CI_CIS_DIVISION).load();
        divisionSetCache = divisionSet.select(CIS_DIVISION).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        divisionList = divisionSetCache.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();

        //3.
        Dataset<Row> userIdSet =  sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",connection ).option("dbtable", SC_USER).load();
        userIdSetCache = userIdSet.select(USER_ID).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        userIdList = userIdSetCache.as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();

ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForDivision = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForDiv = context.broadcast(divisionList, evidenceForDivision);

        ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForCurrency = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForCurrency = context.broadcast(currencySet, evidenceForCurrency);

        ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForUserID = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForUserID = context.broadcast(userIdList, evidenceForUserID);


        //Validation -- Start
        Encoder<RuleParamsBean> encoder = Encoders.bean(RuleParamsBean.class);
        Dataset<RuleParamsBean> ds = new Dataset<RuleParamsBean>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);


        Dataset<RuleParamsBean> validateDataset = ds.map(ruleParamsBean -> validateTransaction(ruleParamsBean,broadcastVarForDiv.value(),broadcastVarForCurrency.value(),
                broadcastVarForUserID.value()),encoder);
        validateDataset.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Comment: what's your broadcast var contains & how many mem it consume?

Comment: @tauitdnmd I have added some code for reference which describes broadcast variables, basically each one of them contains value of one one column of a table, There are 3 broadcast variables.

Comment: which configuration values for: 
spark.driver.memory, 
spark.executor.memory?

Comment: @pasha701 for spark.driver.memory configuration value is default i didn't set it explicitly and for --executor-memory=6G and --num-executors=22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible root cause:** Default value of "spark.driver.memory" 1 Gb only (depends on distributive), it is very small number. If you are reading significant amounts of data on driver, OutOfMemory can occurs easily, advice from exception is correct.

**Solution:** Increase  "spark.driver.memory" and "spark.executor.memory" at least to 16Gb.

Comment: Yes I increased both parameters with 26GB and error was resolved. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to understand it better. You said: "If you are reading significant amounts of data on driver, OutOfMemory can occurs"
But the documentation says:
"Does my data need to fit in memory to use Spark?
No. Spark's operators spill data to disk if it does not fit in memory, allowing it to run well on any sized data. Likewise, cached datasets that do not fit in memory are either spilled to disk or recomputed on the fly when needed, as determined by the RDD's storage level."
Then, why do I have to increase my driver and executor memory? I'm missing something here...

Comment: Guess, your quote is not related to broadcast variables.

Answer (score 0):

[pasha701's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667343/pasha701)
Answer will work when running in remote. But I was facing this for my local & adding following worked for me

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

[More info..](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-broadcast-join-with-example/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20PySpark%20Auto%20Broadcast%20join.&text=This%20can%20be%20set%20up,depends%20on%20the%20executor%27s%20memory.&text=The%20threshold%20value%20for%20broadcast,up%20its%20value%20as%20%2D1.)